# this в javascript понятным языком

Tags: javascript

Хочу видеть простой пример `this` с объяснением на javascript.
Есть такой код:

```
jQuery('#sel1').on('click',function() {
    $("#sel2").html($(this).text())
});
```

Что в этом примере означает `this`? Как понять что `this` именно какой-то селектор?

Comment: У вас это jquery, а не чистый javascript. Единственный способ узнать что означает this в таком контексте - почитать документацию на jquery. Конкретно в обработчики событий JQ в качестве this передает объект на котором произошло событие

Comment: Кстати в данном случае это не селектор, а объект типа DOMElement (или более специфичный)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В описании функции `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), есть следующий строки

> When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be used with jQuery methods, use $( this ).

Когда jQuery вызывает обработчик, то ключевое слово `this` указывает на элемент, которому пришло это событие; для непосредственного связанных событий `this` является элементом, к которому это событие привязано, а при делегированных событиях `this` является элементом удовлетворяющем указанному уточняющему селектору. (Обратите внимание, что `this` может не быть равен `event.target` если событие всплывают из потомка элемента.) Чтобы создать объект jQuery от элемента таким образом, что он может быть использован с методами jQuery, использовать `$(this)`.

Таким образом в приведенном скрипте имеем:

```
jQuery('#sel1').on('click',function() { // прямая привязка события к элементу #sel1
    // this == sel1
    $("#sel2").html($(this).text())
});
```